# What software can I use to convert images to other formats?

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, image-processing, photo-management

I am looking for an application which can do the following:

- Resize one or more images
- Compress images
- Rotate and flip images
- Rename multiple images using a progressive number or a prefix/suffix
- Convert an entire PDF file to a bunch images
- Extract an image from a Windows `.ico` file
- Convert images to `DPX`, `EXR`, `GIF`, `JPEG`, `JPEG-2000`, `PDF`,
  `PhotoCD`, `PNG`, `Postscript`, `SVG`, `TIFF`, and other formats

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Converseen` is just the app for you! **Install** it with:

```
sudo apt-get install converseen
```

This does exactly what you have asked for and more! It supports all the formats you have requested for, and due thanks to the **Magick++ image libraries** it supports over 100 image formats!

**Description:**

```
Batch image converter and resizer
You can convert an unlimited number of images and / or create thumbnails
to any of the most popular formats: DPX, EXR, GIF, JPEG, JPEG-2000, PDF,
PhotoCD, PNG, Postscript, SVG, and TIFF.
Thanks to the Magick++ image libraries it supports more than 100 image formats.
```

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 21):

## ImageMagick

If you want the command-line option, go with `ImageMagick`

Install with `sudo apt-get install imagemagick`

### Usage

Most operations will use the `convert` command. **To convert an image into another format**, you essentially rename your image with the desired file extension.

```
convert image1.png image1.jpg
```

**To resize images**, use the `-resize` option.

```
convert image1.png -resize 200×100 image1.png
```

Note that when using `-resize`, ImageMagick will preserve the image's aspect ratio and fit it into an image with the specified dimensions. To force an image to a particular size, append an `!` to the dimensions.

```
convert image1.png -resize 200×100! image1.png
```

**Rotate images** with the `-rotate` option, using degrees. The following command would rotate an image 90 degrees.

```
convert image1.jpg -rotate 90 image1-rotated.jpg
```

Since this is a command-line tool, you can take advantage of Bash and **perform bulk operations**. The following command would take all PNG files in the current directory, rotate them, and save a new copy of each with “-rotated” added to the beginning of each file name.

```
for file in *.png; do convert $file -rotate 90 rotated-$file; done
```

During any given operation, if the name of your output image is the same as the input image, the operation will overwrite the original image. Otherwise a new image will be created.

You can find more complete documentation [here on the ImageMagick website](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php).

### Limitations

> - Convert an entire PDF file to a bunch images
> - Extract an image from a Windows .ico file

I am unsure if these operations are possible.

> - Convert images to DPX, EXR, GIF, JPEG, JPEG-2000, PDF, PhotoCD, PNG, Postscript, SVG, TIFF, and other formats

I am unsure if all those file formats are supported by ImageMagick

[Answer source](http://www.howtogeek.com/109369/how-to-quickly-resize-convert-modify-images-from-the-linux-terminal/)

Comment: works fine Arch too!

Answer (score 3):

As a complement to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/695786/47206) on `imagemagik`:

That can be added to the **context menu of the file manager** within a desktop file (menu service, action, contract file, etc).

To run a convert command on a selected file and keep the name of the file without adding the input extension into the output name

```
program "$0" "${0%%.*}".extension' %f
```

Example:

```
convert "$0" "${0%%.*}".png' %f
```

Within a Nautilus/PCManFM action:

```
Exec=bash -c 'convert "$0" "${0%%.*}".png' %f
```

Creating that with Nautilus configuration tool, the file is :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Action
ToolbarLabel[en_US]=Convert to png
ToolbarLabel[en]=Convert to png
ToolbarLabel[C]=Convert to png
Name[en_US]=Convert to png
Name[en]=Convert to png
Name[C]=Convert to png
Profiles=profile-zero;

[X-Action-Profile profile-zero]
Basenames=!image/png;image/*;*;
Exec=bash -c  'convert "$0" "${0%%.*}".png' %f
Name[en_US]=Default profile
Name[en]=Default profile
Name[C]=Default profile
```